# How to work around "No provider for t" error?

Tags: angular, typescript

After deploying my App on the production server - GitLab/Docker. I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for t!
at C (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at k (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at t._throwOrNull (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKey (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at t.get (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at je (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at t.get (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at dn (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
at pn (vendor.32b03a44e7dc21762830.bundle.js:1)
```

I believe that such errors were/are posted here on the platform, but they affect totally other features. To be honest, I just can't find the solution for my issue. The strange behavior is that the app was working a fine couple of minutes ago, but suddenly when I called the page once more, I can't load the app because of the mentioned error.

The point is that I even can't localize the affected file, component or module. I even don't know and understand the error!

Any Hint other idea please how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/37

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Unfortunately didn't help... none of the provided hints on  [https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/37](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/37) did help.
And I don't understand why it should handle with Cookies.. I'am not using cookies.

Comment: does it work well on `ng serve` locally  ?

Comment: @RahulSingh: Unfortunately not... error: `ERROR Error: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!` Has it to do with router module?

Comment: Yes i guess you have some spec that you test and that is failing check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45180393/2708210

Comment: @RahulSingh: No, not the unit test files `.spec`. It's fixed now. Was really a issue with router. But you hint with just `ng serve` did give me the idea which files could be affected.

Comment: great if it works @k.vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was an issue with the router which was missing in `imports:[...]`. Here is what I had to add in `add.module.ts`:

```
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode, RouterModule.forRoot(router)
    ],
    entryComponents:[...],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

The point is that I already did have it before in `imports:[]` but for some reason I did remove it without paying attention.