# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "routerLinkActive"

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-runner

I am using the mat nav list component for tab and navigation purpose inside my application. It works perfectly on front end but throws error on test case.

> Getting the below error from karma.

```
 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "routerLinkActive" ("        *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
             [routerLink]="tab.path"
             [routerLinkActive] [ERROR ->]#rla="routerLinkActive"
             [active]="rla.isActive"
             selectedIndex="0"
```

> component.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a
            mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
            [routerLink]="tab.path"
            [routerLinkActive] #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="rla.isActive"
            selectedIndex="0"
        >
            <i class="{{tab.icon}}"></i>
            {{ tab.label }}
        </a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you try removing the square brackets for `routerLinkActive`?

Comment: same error after removing [].

Comment: What's your version of Angular and Angular Material?

Comment: Using Angular Material 2

Comment: How about your Angular version?

Comment: Angular 4 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159734/discussion-between-edric-and-govinda-raj).

Answer (score 4):

With the referene of
[Angular 4 Error: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts in Karma-Jasmine Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159960/angular-4-error-no-provider-for-childrenoutletcontexts-in-karma-jasmine-test) thread added the RouterTestingModule.

Solved the karma error.

Comment: Solved my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add RouterTestingModule to your tests, at the component level. Like this:

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    import { SettingsComponent } from './settings.component';
    import { PageService } from '../../services/page.service';

    import { MaterialModule } from '../shared/material/material.module';

    describe('SettingsComponent', () => {
      let component: SettingsComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SettingsComponent>;
      let pageServiceSpy;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        pageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PageService', ['setPageHeader']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        SettingsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MaterialModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: PageService, useValue: pageServiceSpy}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need this in your test code:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLinkActive]',
  exportAs: 'routerLinkActive'
})
export class RouterLinkActiveDirectiveStub {
}
```

Here `exportAs` is set to 'routerLinkActive'

Comment: this is what i was looking for, we had some existing tests and i didn't want or know if it was possible to convert them over to use RouterTestingModule.  thank you!